# is it possible to keep node in place

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I created a measurement app. 
The problem that I get is the nodes that I placed in the scene moved from the original position.

in the video show that objects move from its original when I moved. https://youtu.be/x6Qvj32xKJU

I placed anchor and printed the position

```
let anchor = ARAnchor(transform: hitTest.worldTransform)

//Add It To The Scene
self.augmentedRealitySession.add(anchor: anchor)

addMarkerNodeFromMatrix(hitTest.worldTransform, anchor: anchor)
```

Is there a way to keep the object in place even you walk far away from it and return to see if it still in the same position, without moving even a bit?

Is it possible to place ARanchor automatically every meter from the phone position?

Is it possible to use it in long-distance?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this lines to place anchor any specfic place

`wrapperNode.position = SCNVector3.positionFromTransform(anchor.transform)
wrapperNode.addChildNode(Body)
scnView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(wrapperNode)`